# Ember app served from node.js using baseUrl/rootUrl with authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ember.js, ember-cli

So, currently I have been using Ember cli to proxy to my api that is on a different port. I am trying to serve up a few routes using only node ('/', '/signIn', '/signUp'), and then once a user is authenticated through the '/signIn' route, serve up the ember app with a token.

As of now I am using 'baseURL' defined in my 'environment.js' of ember-cli, and my ember app is served to '/app/'.

I am getting confused on how one would go about serving up the ember app when a certain node route is accessed and the token is validated. In other words, I can visit my node routes fine, I can visit my ember routes fine using /app/, but am unsure of how to serve up the ember app once my server authenticates the user at '/signIn'. My reasoning for this, is that I do not want to serve up all the javascript assets to the client until I am sure they are an actual user. I am sure that this can be done using node and ember, but have not found much material online regarding such a configuration.

I have done a good amount of research, and the things that have caught my eye are 'baseURL' defined in CLI, 'rootURL' defined in Ember, and this from the Ember CLI page:

```
Integration

When using Ember inside another project, you may want to launch
Ember only when a specific route is accessed. If you’re preloading
the Ember javascript before you access the route, 
you have to disable autoRun:

var app = new EmberApp({
  autoRun: false
});

 To manually run Ember: require("app-name/app")["default"].create({/* app settings */});
```

I know that people in production build the cli app into their '/dist' directory, and then server up the 'index' on their server, but I am not sure if this is the right path to go for development.

To recap, I have an ember-cli app that is getting proxied to my node server. I have a '/', '/signIn', and a '/signUp' route that is handled by node.js completely. I also have an ember app that is served at '/app/' and is making requests to my node app successfully.

What I am unsure of is how to server up the ember app once a user is verified at '/signUp' of my node server.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated. I am very new to this stuff, so please be gentle. I have researched this for two business days while consulting with senior engineers, and they have no clue about frameworks such as Ember.